# Ajax request works in IE 9.0 but not Firefox 24.6

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, firefox

This javascript function works fine when opened in IE 9 but when I try to open it in Firefox 24.6 i get the ajax failure message.

```
  var committeeDiv = document.getElementById("committeeDiv");
        if(committeeDiv != null){
            var url = location.search; // ?com=mc/oc/bic
            var com = String(url.substring(url.indexOf("?")+1, url.length)); //com=bic/mc/oc

            var id;
            var comURL;
            if (com != null && com.length > 0){
                id = String(com.substring(com.indexOf("=")+1, com.length)); // bic/mc/oc
        comURL = 'http://www.example.com/public/content/markets_operations/committees/committee_intros/' + id +'.htm'; 
    }

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: comURL,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(response) {
            committeeDiv.innerHTML=response.responseText; 
        },
        failure: function(response){
            alert("Failed to load Committee Header. Please contact support");
        }
    }); 

    document.getElementById(id).className = "active"; // highlights current page in menu
```

This is the failure I get.

--

```
[08:26:48.008] OPTIONS http://www.example.com/public/content/markets_operations/committees/committee_intros/mc.htm?_dc=1407932807608 [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 20ms]
```

Comment: Post the failure response too.

Comment: Looks like the server is rejecting the request for some reason.  You _might_ be able to get more info if you send using `HEAD` instead of `GET`.  Seems like maybe there's something different between the two browsers in terms of security (maybe IE is already authenticated?)  That's where I'd start... Sorry it's not more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was calling out to an external domain and Firefox doesn't allow that. So instead of using this:

```
comURL = 'http://www.example.com/public/content/markets_operations/committees/committee_intros/' + id +'.htm';
```

This seemed to work fine:

```
comURL = '/public/content/markets_operations/committees/committee_intros/' + id +'.htm';
```